# If i delete the middle data in a database table how can i update the other data sequence into asc order again?

Tags: php, sql, database

So here are my database table which include this 5 records:

[image]

so when I delete the middle record or the first record how can i update the other seq number into asc order again?
 is that possible by doing this with sql or php?

For example: 
If I delete the 2nd record so the INV03 seq number will become 2 or
If i delete the 1st record so the INV02 seq number will become 1

Expected result:

[image]

any solution on this?

Comment: There is absolutely no point in doing such a reorder. Just leave your table as is. Even when you remove the said record, the sort order would still be maintained. (e.g ORDER BY seq).

Comment: my illustration is a bit wrong it should be the same inv such as INV01 for all 5 record I set the seq is because in storing invoice outstanding payment record and knowing there are how many invoice payment have make by this inv id so when there is an edit on the number for crt, dec so i can use the inv and seq to find back the record to do further edit purpose....

Comment: `select id, inv, row_number() over (partition by inv order by id) as seq, crt, dec, total from mytable;` gets you a sequence number within each inv, without storing it in the table. much better to compute it when you need it then to store it and have to worry about it getting out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want the sequence number within each INV value. You can just use ROW_NUMBER() in conjunction with PARTITION BY to number within each inv and ORDER BY to make sure there's a consistent assignment of sequence numbers (in this case, each inv group is sorted by ID, but you can pick anything that isn't subject to change).

```
> select * from mytable; -- notice no seq stored, not grouped by inv 
id|inv|crt|dec|total
1|INV01|10000|100|9900
2|INV01|9900|100|9800
3|INV02|9800|100|9700
4|INV01|9700|100|9600
5|INV03|9600|100|9500

> select id, inv, 
    row_number() over (partition by inv order by id) as seq, 
    crt, dec, total from mytable; -- get seq num within each INV 
id|inv|seq|crt|dec|total
1|INV01|1|10000|100|9900
2|INV01|2|9900|100|9800
4|INV01|3|9700|100|9600
3|INV02|1|9800|100|9700
5|INV03|1|9600|100|9500
```